# What's meaning of "make (sth) of yourself"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could someone please explain the sentence for me? And any citation of such usage?

> You’ve heard about what you make of yourself when you assume things.

This is from the book *[Hacking for Dummies, 4th edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118380932)* .

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, the allusion is to a saying *"when you assume things you make an ass out of (yo)u and me"*, which I recall hearing in *The Silence of the Lambs* and can be found in numerous places on the net.

Normally, to *make something of yourself* would be to achieve a notable or successful place in society, but that isn't what is intended here.

Comment: To clarify, the saying of "when you assume things you make an ass out of you and me" stems from the following:  Assume = Ass + u + me.  Get it?  *nudge nudge*

Answer (score 2):

There is a tacit understanding in the statement that you will often make a fool of yourself when you assume things.

Answer (score 2):

There is a clichéd maxim in US usage that says

> When you *assume*, you make an **ASS** out of **U** and **ME**

It is often illustrated in written form by writing **ASSUME** and then inserting slashes to emphasize the narration

> **ASS/U/ME**